# java xml parsing for ISO-8859-9

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a string to xml for ISO-8859-9. My code is :

```
private Document stringToXML(String input)
{
  DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder builder;
  builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();           
  return builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes("ISO-8859-9")));     
}
```

if input includes just utf-8 characters, code runs correctly but input includes any special character like 'ğ' it throws "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException:"
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Did you check, whether ISO-8859-9 is supported? Use Charset.isSupported("ISO-8859-9") to check for it...

Comment: Does the XML string specify a charset in its declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28org.xml.sax.InputSource%29) a [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) via an [InputSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html#InputSource%28java.io.Reader%29).

Comment: how can i set charset in that form?

Comment: Why would you want to/need to? Strings are always UTF-16.

Comment: I tried that, but this time i'm getting  "[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file."

Comment: Then it sounds like your data is malformed (i.e. not XML.) What is the source of the string?

Comment: i solved the problem by using inputsource.Besides i realize that if string is empty, parse method gives fatal error. Anyway, Thank you for your help. you were very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If the input contains UTF-8 characters, then it is NOT an ISO-8859-9 stream.  Parse it as UTF-8 or convert it to ISO-8859-9 before trying to parse.  You only ever get one character set per document, trying to mix makes the whole thing meaningless.

Comment: I'm not mixing 2 set. Utf-8 and ISO-8859-9 sets have many common characters.